# Can all kinds of pure non-entangled states be cloned?

Tags: no-cloning-theorem

Is it correct to say that for an $n$-qubit system,  we can clone all kinds of pure non-entangled states, without violating the no-cloning theorem?

That is, is the correct interpretation for the proof of cloning theorem shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem), to be that if such a cloning operator $U$ exists, such an operator $U$ would not be a linear operator, but nonetheless $U$ can still act on only non-entangled, mutually orthogonal states?

Entangled linear superpositions of those states in the set are not included instead, because then $U$ would not be a linear operator.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi 王天羿, I have tried editing your post for readability. Please let me know if this is the spirit of your question!

Comment: @MarkS Yep! Thanks!

Comment: @Community Hi, is my question ready to be open to answer?

Comment: I don't think entanglement is important for no-cloning. Even with a single qubit and only pure states you have the no-cloning theorem.

Comment: @M.Stern Based on the proof linked in wiki, it proves that orthogonal states can be cloned using the same cloning operation U. The reason why I mention entanglement  is that it will break the orthogonality. However, entangled pure states should be cloned using the same U if U is a linear operator (since entangled pure states is simply a linear combination of pure non-entangled pure states).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the non-entangled part that's important in your statement. The important part is that *any* mutually orthogonal states can be cloned (provided you know what the set of states is).

Comment: So does it mean that it's practically possible to clone mutually orthogonal states? If that's true, that cloning operator U is not a linear operator, right?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "practically possible". It is certainly theoretically possible. The cloning operator *is* linear. It is the linearity that prevents non-orthogonal states from being cloned.